# How do i check if the elements in a list are contained in other list?

Tags: python, string, list, contains, exists

I´m new to Python and I´m having a problem. I have 2 lists containing the names of the columns of a dataset: one has all the columns names (columnas = total.columns.values.tolist()); and the other one has a subset of them ( in the form of "c = [a,b,c,d,c,e,...]".

I would like to know how could I check if each element in "c" is contained in the longer list "columnas". The result i have been trying to get is as it follows ( this is just an example):

a: True 
b: True
c: False
...

Looking forward to your answers, Santiago

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community. please consider providing more information about you issue as for example a chunk of code. that way we'll help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what is called a "dictionary-comprehension" to form your result:

```
columnas = ['a', 'b', 'z']
c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e']
contained = {x : x in columnas for x in c}
```

which gives `contained` as `{'a': True, 'b': True, 'c': False, 'd': False, 'e': False}`.

Answer (score 1):

`a=[ ]
for i in c:
  if i in columns:
     a.append(true)
  else:
     a.append(false)`

a=[ ]
for i in c:
  if i in columns:
     a.append(true)
  else:
     a.append(false)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked as well; the only difference is that @Joe ´s method shows the name of the column, while your output is the index.